# PublisherAdView not refreshing Ad onResume()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, admob, onresume

In my Android application I have used a PublisherAdView. I want to refresh the Ad(show a new Ad) every time the onResume() is called. So I have the following code.. But it loads the same Ad every time and doesn't work as expected.

Here is the code.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    resetAdRequest();
    if (publisherAdRequest == null)
        return;
    if (adPublisherMediumRectangle != null) {
        adPublisherMediumRectangle.loadAd(new PublisherAdRequest.Builder().build());
        adPublisherMediumRectangle.refreshDrawableState();
    }

}
```

Could any of you please let me know what I can do to fix this issue.

Appreciate your help,
Smitha

Comment: I think you have to destroy the `PublisherAdView` and recreate it again.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I have implemented this. Seems to be working fine. Will try it out for a while and let you know. Thanks again.

Comment: @yugidroid: I tried this out.. it refreshes but not all the time. May be 60% of the times. Don't know how it can be set to refresh all the time. Still looking for solution.